# How are the rules of phonetics/pronunciation named in standard german?

Tags: pronunciation, terminology, phonetics

I am searching a scientific term for the pronunciation rules covering the following: The vowel in *Stamm* is short, but the vowel in *Wal* is long.

In German, pronunciation is [Aussprache](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aussprache_der_deutschen_Sprache), but I am looking for a more specific term related to the specific rules of combination of vowels and consonants. Which part of Aussprache is it? I found [Phonotaktik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonotaktik) but I am not sure if it is the correct one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An integral part of phonetics ([Phonetik](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetik) in German) is research not only on rules of the quality but also on rules for the quantity of a vowel.

The German term for this would be

- *[Vokalquantität](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vokalquantit%C3%A4t)* or *Vokallänge*